# How do you access underlying PowerShell runspace from C# Cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I am building some PowerShell cmdlets using the C#/.NET APIs and have a cmdlet that needs access to all the currently imported modules. If I run `Get-Module` in the terminal I can see 10+ modules loaded, but when my cmdlet runs:

```
using(var ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.Current))
{
    var modules = ps.AddCommand("Get-Module").Invoke<PSModuleInfo[]>();
    /// ...
}
```

`modules` here is empty. Its almost like a scoping problem, but I thought `RunspaceMode.Current` would allow you to access that underlying runspace that was opened with you first open the `pwsh` shell.

I must be missing something or misunderstanding exactly how runspaces work.

Comment: "a cmdlet that needs access to all the currently imported modules" sounds like a code smell... what is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well tbh this isn't exactly the code I am dealing with, just a basic example. However, my code does some dynamic PS module proxy generation and after my cmdlet is "done" I need it to clean up after itself. So I am trying to call "Remove-Module" on these dynamic modules and nothing seems to happen when that is ran from inside the cmdlet. It appears to be the same issue that "Get-Module" has though and its a simpler example which is why I used that in my question.

Comment: If I wrote my Cmdlet in PS directly this would all work, so I guess I don't understand why this doesn't work as soon as you try it in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to mess around with the invoking runspace directly from inside a cmdlet - *it's already busy executing your cmdlet*. You also cannot invoke a `PSCmdlet` directly from another, for the same reason.

Instead, you'll want to use `PSCmdlet.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript()` to have the runtime execute a script for you (just like if you had a `Get-Module` statement in a PowerShell function):

```cs
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "ModuleProxy")]
public class GetModuleProxyCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    // ...

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        foreach(var module in InvokeCommand.InvokeScript("Get-Module"))
        {
            WriteObject(module);
        }
    }
}
```

---

That being said, if what you're doing affects the environment in a way that requires you to execute `Remove-Module` or clean stuff up in the callers context, you're probably much better off doing your work in a separate runspace anyway :)

Comment: Ok thanks that at least clears up "why" it doesn't seem to a let you do this. I am doing some very non-traditional things here with PS so its not as straightforward as one might think. These "extra" proxies are transient and meant to only act as a facade to provide caching of connection/auth. It's a long story, haha. But I will try to do this another way similar to what you stated. Thanks

Comment: @MattHintzke That doesn't sound especially non-traditional or weird at all - in fact it sounds a lot like [JEA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview) :)

Comment: Haha, ok well that is good. Since you seem like a PowerShell guru you might be interested in seeing what we are building. https://www.skykick.com/manage. Aims to help reduce the cognitive load of IT management as SaaS, IaaS, and PaaS becomes more complex.